# CURL HTTP2 request

Tags: curl

I would like to know if someone successfully managed to send a push notification through the new APNS API (HTTP2)using CURL.

An example request's given on the [APNs Provider API page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW10)

Here's how the request must be:

HEADERS

```
\- END_STREAM

\+ END_HEADERS

:method = POST

:scheme = https

:path = /3/device/00fc13adff785122b4ad28809a3420982341241421348097878e577c991de8f0

host = api.development.push.apple.com

apns-id = eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b

apns-expiration = 0

apns-priority = 10

content-length = 33
```

DATA

```
\+ END_STREAM

{ "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
```

But with the following command I get error "curl: (16) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: error_code = 8":

```
curl \

--verbose \

--http2 \

--cert <APPLICATION_CERT_FILE> \

--key <APPLICATION_KEY_FILE> \

--header "Content-Type: application/json" \

--header ":method: POST" \

--header ":path: /3/device/<DEVICE ID>" \

--data '{ "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }' \

https://api.development.push.apple.com
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 17):

I have successfully sent push notifications from cURL using the following:

```
curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"Test Push","sound":"default"}}' \
--cert /path/to/cert/cert.pem:SECURE_PASSWORD \
-H "apns-topic: com.app.identifier" --http2 \
https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/DEVICE_ID
```

This is using `curl` version `7.48.0`, installed by [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.48.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0) libcurl/7.48.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.5 nghttp2/1.9.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

Notice, however, that I get the same error as you do when using our development certificate on the production server: `https://api.push.apple.com/`

> curl: (16) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: error_code = 8

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the  dev vs. prod URL.  That was my exact issue!

Comment: As of macOS High Sierra, the "curl" command as in-built now supports http2 so you don't need to use home-brew to install an alternate "curl."

Comment: YES; I too made the mistake with the https URL which needs to be api.sandbox.push.apple.com for development,

Answer (score 12):

### Certificate based provider authentication

```
curl -v
     -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}'
     -H "apns-topic: <your app bundle ID>" 
     --http2 
     --cert cert.pem
     https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/<device token>
```

### Token based provider authentication

```
curl -v 
     -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}'
     -H "apns-topic: <your app bundle ID>" 
     -H "authorization: bearer xxxx.yyyy.zzzz" 
     --http2
     https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/<device token>
```

You will need to generate your JWT token and sign it using ES256. This is out of scope here (it's easy to find many libraries on a quick Google search).

Answer (score 0):

1. remove --header ":method: POST" (--data will make it use POST)
2. remove -header ":path: /3/device/"

   The :path part is what you want on the right side of the host name in the URL, so specify a URL like perhaps `https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/<DEVICE ID>`
3. That said, getting a HTTP/2 level stream error like that is very unexpected and would rather indicate a lower level problem somewhere...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The point is to experiment with command line before implementing that in C (push server). The problem is that the connection to _https://api.development.push.apple.com_ must be first initialized and kept persistent at workers initialization stage.   Request must be be done then with changing paths according to the device to target...

Comment: I cannot give the list of all URLs at initialization time. Reason is that device ids are simply not known by advance since it's a server waiting for incoming requests which are supposed to contain these ids. And even the daemon would know them all by advance (but it's not), there's thousand of devices registering/unregistering and each ID will make a path of its own... HTTP2 is designed to keep a connection with the main host and perform queries through this unique connection by using different paths. Keeping a dedicated connection per whole path is past and what HTTP2 want to make obsolete.

Comment: Concerning the low level error, I noticed it still occurs even when removing the invalid **--header ":path..."** . But using **--cert** and **--key** options pointing to valid files as follow: **curl --verbose --http2 --cert <APPLICATION_CERT_FILE> --key <APPLICATION_KEY_FILE> --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }' api.development.push.apple.com**

Comment: I can't figure out if the problem is coming from **libnghttp2** or not but what is sure is it enters in the following if statement: **if(stream->error_code != NGHTTP2_NO_ERROR)**...

Comment: If I remove **--cert ...** and **--key ...** the command finally returns what the server replied:  **curl --verbose --http2 --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }' api.development.push.apple.com**, but of course the request cannot be served as APNS requires a client certificate to work.

Comment: In C code I'll use **libcurl** as I already use it for few other tasks. The typical workflow is to connect first, then build **stream HEADERS frame** containing the varying trailing path by adding chunks, **stream DATA frame** containing data and finally pass that stream to the server, get the result and close it, until the next one to proceed using a different path and different data but keeping the same connection.